# Is any way in lucene to prepare cach for all index before first query?

Tags: java, performance, lucene

The first query that I launch is slower than second time with same query.

I am wondering why this could be happening, is it because the index had to go from disk to memory? Then, even more difficult to understand for me . In case I restart my computer behaves like the first time, so it goes slowly only the first time with the index.

Is any way in lucene to prepare cach for all index before first query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be quite useful to "warm up" the index when first starting.

There isn't some magic method to call though, no.  You've already got a good hint as to how to do it, since the search goes faster the second time.  The way to warm up the index is to run some *typical* queries.  It's important that when warming up, you run the sort of queries that will actually be occurring in practice.  You're building the cache for lucene to search on after all.  If you are building up a cache for data no one is actually searching for, you are just wasting time.

If you are Sorting (that is, by a field, or other custom sort, rather than score), make sure you have some warm up queries are using the same Sort.